# PHP mail attachment bad headers?

Tags: php, linux, windows, email, postfix-mta

I'm building a service to send pdf attachments to some email destinations. Recently I have found that some people can't receive the emails properly:
- headers go into email body
- attachments get corrupted

By having a bunch of tests, I'm having a clue that the problem might be the PHP_EOL because when I change it (from \n to \r\n or vice-versa) some people receive it well and others don't.
Is it a coding problem or a server problem?

```
    $separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;
// attachment name
$filename = "Convite.pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = $content;
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = "From: Myserver<".$from_mail.">\nBCC: suporte@myserver.com".$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\tboundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //
$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

//message
$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";
```

Comment: I suggest you use a library like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer to do this for you.

Comment: I second Amal's suggestion

Comment: i used swiftmailer and it seems to be working. Any clues why happened? just for me to understand a bit how line break works